# Unable to run cosmosDB trigger locally with Azure Function Core Tools

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, serverless, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to run an azure function locally on my laptop using the Azure Functions Core Tools. Notice that this function is configured as a **cosmosDB trigger**

I was partially inspired by the instructions in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)

I started by creating a function called **MyFirstFunction** with the following commands (and inserting the required inputs when prompted):

```
func init
func start
```

My generated **javascript** function is (the same the Azure portal creates for the same kind of template function):

```
module.exports = function (context, documents) {
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
        context.log('Document Id: ', documents[0].id);
    }
    context.done();
}
```

My generated **function.json** is:

```
{
    "bindings":
    [
        {
          "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
          "name": "documents",
          "direction": "in",
          "leaseCollectionName": "leases"
        }
    ]
}
```

My generated **local.settings.json** is

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

Given this setup I try to run the function by executing:

```
func host start
```

Everything runs fine in the console output until the error message:
**Unable to configure binding 'documents' of type 'cosmosDBTrigger'. This may indicate invalid function.json properties. Can't figure out which ctor to call.**

What I missing? I was supposed to trigger the function through an http POST to:

```
http://localhost:{port}/admin/functions/{function_name}
```

as explained in the tutorial linked above (being this function a cosmosDB trigger) but the function cannot even be loaded after this error.

What am I missing to run a cosmosDB trigger locally?

Many thanks.

Comment: notice that I have also run: func extensions install before starting the function.

Comment: notice that if I follow the same procedure creating a HTTP trigger it works fine.

Comment: Is this a v1 or v2 function app?

Comment: It’s a V2 function app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `local.settings.json` and `function.json` lack necessary configuration of cosmosdb connection string.

See [cosmosdb trigger document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---javascript-example).

function.json

```
{
    "bindings":
    [
        {
          "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
          "name": "documents",
          "direction": "in",
          "leaseCollectionName": "leases",

          // Missed in your code
          "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnectionString",
          "databaseName": "<Get db name>",
          "collectionName": "<Get coll name>",
          "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
        }
    ]
}
```

local.settings.json

```
 {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
        "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

         //Missed in your code
        "CosmosDBConnectionString":"<Get connection string from Azure portal>"
    }
 }
```

Note that in latest version of function core tools(2.0.1-beta.31), no need to register CosmosDB extension if you use `func new` to create CosmosDB Trigger, tools will install it automatically.

After this problem solved, if you met another error about `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll`

```
The listener for function 'Functions.CosmosDb' was unable to start.
The listener for function 'Functions.CosmosDb' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)). 
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
```

Just install one package to fix(See this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/430))

```
func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core -v 2.0.0-preview
```

Then everything should work.

Comment: Just to add to Jerry's answer, you don't need to do a POST to trigger the Function, the whole point of the Cosmos DB Trigger is that the Function triggers when you insert or update a document in the source collection.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Thanks, nice complement. It seems OP tried to follow exactly the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) to test whether it works.

Comment: Thank you all. Works perfectly now!