# Unable to run cosmosDBTrigger after upgrade with Azure Function v4

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-core-tools

I am upgrading an existing Function App into v4 runtime.

I'm running and testing it locally via venv.

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases2",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureWebJobsCosmosDBConnectionString",
      "databaseName": "%DBNameFromKeyVault%",
      "collectionName": "%CollectionNameFromKeyVault%",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
   
    }
  }
```

i have install what on **requirements.txt**.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then **func start**

and i got an error:
**The 'myfunction' function is in error: Unable to configure binding 'documents' of type 'cosmosDBTrigger'. This may indicate invalid function.json properties. Can't figure out which ctor to call.**

This is Azure Functions Core Tools versionL
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667

I have also did **func extension install**. it was installed successfully.

My expectation, since I'm only upgrading the function app from v2 to v4, there's no changes in code except for the versions from the requirements.txt, extensions, and runtime.

Do i miss anything? Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You might need to use `createLeaseContainerIfNotExists` etc? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration

the name of most of the settings changed

Comment: Thank you for this! I have changed it and it removed the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced this issue at my environment and able to get the expected results***

Here I am using below versions alike you

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667
```

I am also fetching the database name and collection name from Key vault.

**`function.json:`**

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
"name": "documents",
"direction": "in",
"leaseCollectionName": "leasesDemo",
"connectionStringSetting": "afreencosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
"databaseName": "%DBNameFromKeyVault%",
"collectionName": "%CollectionNameFromKeyVault%",
"createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
}
]
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {  
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"afreencosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB": "<Your cosmos DB connection string>",
"DBNameFromKeyVault": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<your db name link created in secrets>)",
"CollectionNameFromKeyVault": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<your collection link created in secrets>)"

}
}
```

Try to add the missing details in your **local.settings.json** file like cosmos DB connection string and the database name and the collection name which you are referring from key vault.

As suggested in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199933/unable-to-run-cosmosdb-trigger-locally-with-azure-function-core-tools?rq=2), your issue will get resolved after adding the above parameters in your local setting file.

**`host.json:`**

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
}
}
```

**`requirement.txt:`**

```
azure-functions
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I was able to solve the error on binding. But another error came up though I think its not related on binding.